# Wordpress Plugin help changing the search results page

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I'm in the process of writing a wordpress plugin to update the search functionality of my website. I'm looking at adding in sponsored listings above and below the generated HTML from wordpress on the search page.

The themes are likely to change and I cant seem to find the action/filter/hook to use for the search results page. The main thing I'd like to do is to add a hook/action so that I can pre and post pend HTML to the generated HTML from wordpress.

I have this working on posts, using:

`add_filter( 'the_content', 'callback')`

but this applies the filter to each post, so I cant add this to the search page and I cant seem to get the generated HTML. Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use this template tag is_search() i.e.

```
    <?php
           if ( is_search() ) {
              // our custom code here
             }
     ?>
```

Doc:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_search

Description:
This Conditional Tag checks if search result page archive is being displayed. This is a boolean function, meaning it returns either TRUE or FALSE.

Comment: that's true, but if the search returns 0 results then is_search() will always return 0. which isnt what i'd expect. so i need something that's more obvious. TBH i can determine when a search occurs, what i cant seem to do is edit the HTML that's returned. i think the only option i have is to use shortcodes .... but i dont want that. Long and short. I want to bookend the search results returned. So maybe i can do something within the_loop() to render html on reset() and end()?